# Realtime art project --- input: sound --- output: image (better title?)

Tags: python, audio, real-time, microcontroller, processing

I am not quite sure if I should ask this question here. 
I want to make an art project.
I want to use voice as an input, and an image as output.
The image changes accordingly to the sound.

How can I realise this? Because I need realtime or a delay under 50 ms.
At first I thougt it would be better to use a micro controller.
But I want to calculate huge images, maybe I microcontroller can't do this.
For example I want to calculate 10.000 moving objects.
Could I realise this with windows/linux/mircocontroller?

It would be very good if I could use Python.
Or do you thing processing is a better choice?

Do you need more details?

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought about using a graphical dataflow environment like [Pure Data](http://www.puredata.info) (Pd) or [Max](http://cycling74.com/products/max/)? Max is a commercial product, but Pd is free.

Even if you don't end up using Pd for your final project, it makes an excellent rapid prototyping tool. Whilst the graphics processing capabilities of Pd are limited, there are extensions such as [Gridflow](http://gridflow.ca/) and [Gem](http://gem.iem.at/), which may help you. Certainly with Pd you can analyse incoming sound using the [fiddle~] object, which will give you the overall pitch and frequency/amplitude of individual partials and [env~], which will give you RMS amplitude. You could then very easily map changes in sound (pitch, amplitude, timbre) to various properties of an image such as colour, shapes, number of elements and so on in Gem or Gridflow.

10k moving objects sounds like a heck of a lot even on a modern desktop GPU! Calculating all of those positions on-the-fly is going to consume a *lot* of resources. I think even with a dedicated C++ graphics library like [openFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/), this might be a struggle. You might want to consider an optimisation strategy like pre-rendering aspects of the image, and using the real-time audio control to determine which pre-rendered components are displayed at any given time. This might give the illusion of control over 10k objects, when in reality much of it is pre-rendered.

Good luck!

Comment: Your post help me a lot. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is a good one, PD is very flexible, but if you want something more code oriented and better suited to mixing with MCUs, processing might be better.

Another good way to do it would be to use Csound with the Csound Python API. Csound has a steep learning curve, but tons tons of audio analysis functionality and it's very good for running with low latency. You could definitely analyse an input signal in real time and then send control values out to a graphic environment, scripting both with Python.